# Change Virtualbox Remote Display address?

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, configuration, remote-desktop

The remote display feature doesn't seem to have an option to change the listen address. It's broadcasting on every interface by default -- which I don't want.

[image]

Would it be possible to add a value to the *.vbox config file to achieve this?

```
  <RemoteDisplay enabled="true">
    <VRDEProperties>
      <Property name="TCP/Ports" value="1234"/>
    </VRDEProperties>
  </RemoteDisplay>
```